# jQuery Validate - Url Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use jQuery validate library in order to validate if a user enters a valid url.

The validation must check if the user types `http:// || https://` otherwise it needs to be added.

With the code I have I managed to get just `http://` inserted automatically and as soon the user types It will appear and cannot modify it to `https://` if needed.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3mpjuwcy/2/)

Comment: You want http or https prepended??

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1761988.aspx?Regular+expression+for+Validating+URL+with+or+without+http     please check this

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var regexp = "^http(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$";
return regexp.test(URLValue);
```